# Как сделать отступ чтобы фон был на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: html, css, html5, tailwindcss

Пишу хедер, на новом для меня фреймворке — Tailwind.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs

Проблема следующая, мне нужно сделать отступ контейнером так, чтобы он ограничивал и хедер. Как это реализовать? Или быть может, есть другие варианты получения отступа на основной контент и хедер одновременно, при этом чтобы фон хедера был на полную ширину экрана как в тз.

набросок на бегете: http://vilaf6kh.beget.tech/

ТЗ: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помещаете контейнер внутрь хедера:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    //здесь весь контент хедера
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Я так полагаю, вы даже код не открыли?) У меня так и написано..

Comment: @Andrey, в чём тогда проблема? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Извиняюсь, за вопрос, уже исправил проблему.